# Is there a server-side Websocket client for node.js?

Tags: node.js, client, websocket

I've been using socket.io to create a websocket enabled server in node.js, and its great.   Now i'd like however, to create a server-side client in node.js which can connect to a websocket server elsewhere.  Are there any libraries out there for this?

Thanks

Comment: This question duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842565/is-there-a-browserless-websocket-client-for-node-js-that-does-not-need-to-use-a/8055463#8055463 See my extensive answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/pgriess/node-websocket-client <-- does this one work for you?

Found on this list here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

Comment: This doesn't quite work if we're talking specifically about socket.io -- there is a minimal protocol involved including a heartbeat. Check out the bootstrap code in my example that strips off the header and responds to heartbeats.

Comment: This does work thanks..  its not ideal (as mentioned above), but it does the basics for now

Comment: @Noli I never saw in your comment if you had tried it, so ... my apologies if you had. Perhaps you can contribute some code with any improvements you make?

Answer (score 2):

Not any that are great.

I talked to Guillermo about this on mailing list a couple days ago, see http://groups.google.com/group/socket_io/browse_thread/thread/74e9ff6d7e931f6e

I wrote this as a bootstrap to help in my testing:
https://github.com/jmoyers/mettle/blob/master/test/test-socket.coffee#L18-49

Guillermo is working on one here for 0.7:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node-client

Comment: Thanks for the examples, and links

Answer (score 1):

I've just been working on a project with similar needs: a Node server that acts as a Socket.io server and connects to another service via proper websockets. I used the [`ws` module](https://github.com/einaros/ws) for the websocket client in Node.

Do be aware that, as noted above by Josh, Socket.io is a protocol on top of web sockets.