# Update a web page using socket.io when database is updated by another page

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm starting playing with `NodeJS` and `Socket.IO` and I've got a question regarding communication between pages of my application.

I've got a `Node JS script (get_new_data)` which is periodicaly executed using a cron task. This script will get information through Internet, parse them and write them in a PG Database. This is ok.

I've got a secondary script `(show_last_data)` using `Node/Express/Socket.io` that displays the last information of the DB when it is executed. This is also ok, right now.

What I would like now, is that the script `show_last_data` would be notified when new data are inserted in the database and the corresponding display divs to be updated.

Can `get_new_data` connect to `show_last_data` even if it is not the server that produces the page ? Or should I manage this in another way ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a way to manage this using socket.io-client.
This page was particulary helpful to solve my question : [socket.io as a client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042466/socket-io-as-a-client)